# Pass data to spring boot controller using thymeleaf from javascript innerHtml

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I will create table row in javascript , in table row I have some input field and now I want to access data from this fields using thymeleaf

```
function myCreateFunction2() {
        var table = document.getElementById("mdlTable2");
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML = "Item";
        cell2.innerHTML = '<input id="item" type="number" value="">';
        cell3.innerHTML = "UOM";
        cell4.innerHTML = '<textarea></textarea>';
        cell5.innerHTML = '<button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="save()">Save</button></form>';
        cell6.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="myDeleteFunction2()">Remove</button>';

    }
```

Comment: what is the issue are you facing?

Comment: i want to send data from the table to my spring boot controller but can not resolve it

Comment: Edit the question and add the details and error are you seeing.

Comment: I have edited question description

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `name` to each input and then on your controller, ask for those parameters. Let's assume you you expected url is `/edit`.

**JS**

```
function myCreateFunction2() {
        var table = document.getElementById("mdlTable2");
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML = "Item";
        cell2.innerHTML = '<input id="item" type="number" value="" name="id">';
        cell3.innerHTML = "UOM";
        cell4.innerHTML = '<textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>';
        cell5.innerHTML = '<button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="save()">Save</button></form>';
        cell6.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="myDeleteFunction2()">Remove</button>';
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String edit(@RequestParam("id") String id,
                   @RequestParam("description") String description { ... }
```

**Save (JS)**

Now, since you don't have a form, if you want to submit your data, you will need one. In this case, we will do it using `javascript`.

```
function save() {

    // First, let's create the form.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "/edit";

    // Now, let's add the inputs.
    var id = document.getElementById('id');
    var description = document.getElementBy('description');
    form.appendChild(id);
    form.appendChild(description);

    // Submit the form.
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();

}
```

Another, more easy way, would be to wrap your html code in a form. Of course, you would need to duplicate your code, since you would need both the edit and the delete form.

Hope it helps.

Comment: in that case you need to apply controller function to javascript any how

Comment: After reading the comments on your question I finally understood your needs. I edited my question. Hope it helps. By the way, Thymeleaf is not needed for this, unless you wanted to map an object. If you wanted that, you would need to wrap everything with a form. There would be no escaping it.

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error or it simply doesn’t submit?

Comment: I think I see my problem, I forgot to add the form to the body. I just edited my answer. Should work now.